# How do I add myself to the "wheel" group to use cvs?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, cvs

I am on a Mac (Snow Leopard) and I would like to add myself to the "wheel" group? How do I do that? I there a way I can see all the groups am I in?

Comment: `root` is the only member of the `wheel` group, and should remain the only member. If you have to do something that requires `wheel`, you should use the command `sudo`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can see what groups you are in using the `id` command:

```
$ id testacc 
uid=1089(testacc) gid=1096(testacc) groups=1096(testacc)
```

the `dscl` utility can be used to add users to groups:

```
$ dscl . append /Groups/admin GroupMembership username
```

where **username** is the user short name of the user you wish to add to the particular group.

Answer (score 13):

There is arguably a better command to check what group one belongs to.  The "groups" command.  Example:

```
$ groups

staff _developer _lpoperator _lpadmin _appserveradm admin _appserverusr localaccounts everyone com.apple.access_ssh com.apple.access_screensharing
```

The command to add group wheel:

```
$ sudo dscl . append /Groups/wheel GroupMembership username
```

Where "username" is your username.  Then re-run "groups" to see that you have indeed been added to group wheel, like so:

```
$ groups                                                  
staff _developer _lpoperator _lpadmin _appserveradm admin _appserverusr localaccounts everyone wheel com.apple.access_ssh com.apple.access_screensharing
```

Comment: groups(1) does work as well, but it's deprecated in favour of id(1) (at least as of OSX 10.7).